# Meteor not refreshing browser when only using Sublime Text as the IDE

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, sublimetext3, sublimetext2

Pretty straightforward. Whenever I used Sublime Text as my IDE and save a 'write-protected file', the changes are not detected, the browser isn't refreshed whatsoever.

However, if I use Visual Studio Code, I have no problem at all.

Why is this occurring?

Comment: What is the file you are saving?

Comment: For the record, it _should_ work and does work for me. So there's a good chance you're either editing a different dev dir than the one that meteor is running from, or you're editing a file that doesn't trigger the refresh, etc. @Mikkel 's question should help get to the bottom of it.

Comment: If you're editing a write protected file, it sounds like you are editing the build artifacts rather than the source code. Meteor only watches the source code for changes